# How do I apply a GestureListener to an EditText?

Tags: java, android, view, gesture, double-click

I found this code that shows how to create a GestureListener to listen for a double-tap, but I've been unable to figure out how to apply it to my EditText, so that the double-tap is only detected when the user double-taps on the EditText.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class MyView extends View {

GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
            // creating new gesture detector
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

// skipping measure calculation and drawing

    // delegate the event to the gesture detector
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
}


private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
    // event when double tap occurs
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        Log.d("Double Tap", "Tapped at: (" + x + "," + y + ")");

        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just implement the double tap logic myself with onTouchListener:

```
 EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    edit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        long oldTime = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                if(System.currentTimeMillis()-oldTime<300){
                    Log.i("TAG", "Double Click");
                }
                oldTime=System.currentTimeMillis();


            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: How do you implement the double-tap logic?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It helped me to see that I could do without GestureListener in this particular case. Hopefully someone will post an actual answer to the question though, as I'm sure I (and others) will have need for it in the future.

Comment: Hey, I just threw on the logic :) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Steven is right ,you can use a counter variable with onTouchListener , when counts reaches 2 call requestfocus() on editText .Do the logic for MotionEvent.Action_Down case.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to figure out what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question but rather an alternative method that I have resorted to for detecting double-tapping on an EditText.


Here is the code that I'm currently using.
You don't necessarily have to use all of this code. I included some extra code just to help you determine where you should place the double-tap detection code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

public long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
public long elapsedTime1 = 0;


@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   final  EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

   myEditText.setOnTouchListener(new myDoubleClickDetector());
   }


   public class myDoubleClickDetector implements OnTouchListener 
   {
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
      {
         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
         {
         elapsedTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime1;
            if (elapsedTime1 > 500) //500 is the Windows standard double-click delay .. it works well
            {
            startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return false;
            }
            else
            {
               if (elapsedTime1 > 50) //this 50 is just to help prevent errors .. you can change to 0 if you want
               {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You just double-tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
               return true;
               }
            }
         }
      return false;   
      }
   }

}
```

And here are the lines of that code that matter most:

```
public long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
public long elapsedTime1 = 0;

myEditText.setOnTouchListener(new myDoubleClickDetector());

   public class myDoubleClickDetector implements OnTouchListener 
   {
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
      {
         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
         {
         elapsedTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime1;
            if (elapsedTime1 > 500) //500 is the Windows standard double-click delay .. it works well
            {
            startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return false;
            }
            else
            {
               if (elapsedTime1 > 50) //this 50 is just to help prevent errors .. you can change to 0 if you want
               {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You just double-tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
               return true;
               }
            }
         }
      return false;   
      }
   }
```